# Finding Baptism Record for John Bohling who was born 1843 in Hanover, Germany?

Tags: germany, baptism-records, 1840s, lower-saxony

I am trying to find a baptism record for John Bohling, Born 14 Feb 1843 in the city of Hanover, Niedersachsen, Germany, Died 15 April 1883 in Utica, New York.

- His death date has been verified with an obituary in the Utica, New York newspaper.
- His birth date was passed down from John Bohling himself through his direct descendants.
- His wife's name was Juliane Julia Bottcher:

  - She was born in Holstein, Germany in 1848.
  - Her death was in Utica, New York 5 February 1896 and also verified through an obituary in the Utica, New York newspaper

---

Timeline for John Bohling

- 14 Feb 1843 - born in the city of Hanover (Germany) (family documents)
- abt Feb 1843 - baptism?, but which religious denomination, which parish?
- bef <strike>1869</strike> 1867- arrival in USA
- marriage probably bef 1869 - USA <strike>or Germany?</strike>
  Likely candidate: [John Bohleng (Bohling) & Juliane W.C.M.Pattcher (Pacher)](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:2HVQ-69M) on 12 October 1867 in Portland, Maine (Maine Vital Records, 1670-1921) - but parents not named, and record is a copy: original (or the marriage intention) may have additional information
- abt 1869 - birth in New York of eldest child Henry (per 1870 & 1880 censuses)
- 1870 - residence Utica, Oneida, New York, United States, [1870 US Census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M8V7-1VG). Age 27, born Hanover, with spouse Julia (age 23, born Holstein), and son Henry (age 1, born New York)
- 1880 - residence Utica, Oneida, New York, United States, [1880 US Census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MZXN-PGP). Age 38, born Germany, with spouse Julia Bohling (age 34, born Germany), and 5 children (11y - 1y, all US-born) Henry Bohling, Carl Bohling, Albert Bohling, John Bohling, William Bohling
- 15 April 1883 - died in Utica, New York (obituary). Buried in New Forest Cemetery, Utica (Findagrave memorial, [John Bohling](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=%20126691899))

Comment: Does your evidence of birth in Hanover specify the city of Hanover or the Kingdom of Hanover? The Kingdom included most of today's Niedersachsen, and was annexed by Prussia in 1866.

Comment: Hi, Ken -- I have closed your question because it is too broad.  In the [help] we have some guidance on [what is on-topic](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and what kinds of [questions to avoid](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."  Once you've edited your post to include a focused question and shown us what you've tried so far, we can open the question again.

Comment: If you already have birth/baptism and/or death/burial records for John can you include references or links to them in your question, please?  If not, then let us know that you do not and your question could become about seeking one or other of them.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it.

Comment: Ken thanks for the edit and additional details.. but I still don't see any specific question other than "looking for relatives".. there is a ton of different questions that could be asked.. maybe starting with some specific ones. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @CRSouser that we still need a specific question.  I am going to assume that what you are seeking is John's baptism record because that is likely to name his parents.  To help find that, or to try and find his parents' names by other means, if it cannot be located, you may want to fill in more of the timeline for John like his marriage record, children's births, census records, etc.

Comment: Unless you know WHERE to look, finding a baptismal record is a needle in a whole field of haystacks. A marriage record or will might also mention either parents or a specific place of birth. At this time, we don't have any way of knowing whether Ken has even searched the available US-records (like the 1870 & 1880  and New York state censuses), immigration, naturalization, military, etc. as recommended in other answers to similar questions here